# Spring Security: content-type-options

Tags: spring-security, content-type

I have a problem with Spring Security, 
since I updated Spring Security versione from 3.* to 4.0.* i notice a lot of problem using Internet Explorer 8+ with my applications.
I found that is possible to disable **Content Type Options** including this directive in the Spring  tag:

```
<content-type-options disabled="true"/>
```

But in this way i'm vulnerable from XSS attacks. There is a way to disable the content sniffing for only png file?

Thanks in advance for all kind of help or info